# display image at mousepointer when hovering over an image

Tags: jquery

The idea is 'simple', use jQuery to display the image at the mouspointer when you hover over the different images...

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $img = $("img").mouseover();
  $img.mouseover(function() {
    // console.log($img);
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;
    // console.log("X: " + event.pageX + ", Y: " + event.pageY)
    // console.log(x);
    console.log(y);

  });
});
```

```css
#largeImage {
  position: absolute;
  padding: .5em;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="logo1.png"><img src="logo1-small.png" alt="logo1" /></a>
<a href="toolset.png"><img src="toolset-small.png" alt="toolset" /></a>
<a href="selector.png"><img src="selector-small.png" alt="selector" /></a>
```

So... I haven't gotten very far yet I'm afraid.

Comment: `var $img = $("img").mouseover();  $img.mouseover(function() {`  doesn't make much sense, try using `var $img = $('img'); ` only (and then your $img.mouseover... stuff

Comment: I might be missing goal you're trying to achieve, but why couldn't you use css and add a psuedo-class for image hover to toggle the display?

Comment: The image has to move with the mouse as the mouse moves around, and also change when the mouse goes to a different image... 
Like on this (short) video: https://youtu.be/oJKpveh2dhs

Comment: better get some JS plugin to do it , this will be easier way